# Can I pass a parameter to a callback function of Google Charts Load?

Tags: javascript, laravel, google-visualization

I'm trying to dynamically show charts on PDF using Google Charts, SnappyPDF and Laravel, based initially on [this](https://medium.com/@almestaadmicadiab/laravel-snappy-for-pdf-with-charts-e5c9b757d6dd) post. I had send a Laravel `$arrayChart` variable inside the view to test, and get success with that:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
        function init() {
          google.load("visualization", "1.1", {
            packages: ["corechart"],
            callback: 'drawCharts'
          });
        }

        function drawCharts() {
          var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable({!! $arrayChart !!});
          var options = {
            title: 'My Daily Activities',
          };
          var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('columnchart'));
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }
      </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="init()">
     <div id="columnchart"></div>

    </body>
```

As it seems, i have a div with 'columnchart' id on page and render the chart on him. But, what i really have to do is pass the dynamic data-set of Chart to the `drawCharts()` function to dynamically show the data, something like that:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function init(data) {
      google.load("visualization", "1.1", {
        packages: ["corechart"],
        callback: 'drawCharts(data)'
      });
    }

    function drawCharts(obj) {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(obj);
      var options = {
        title: 'My Daily Activities',
      };
      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('columnchart'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="init({!! $arrayChart !!})">
  <div id="columnchart"></div>
</body>
```

Doesn't work. How can i pass a parameter to the google.load callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way, is to pass a reference to the callback function, instead of a string, and bind the parameter to that reference:

`callback: drawCharts.bind(null, data)`

See [Function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

Alternatively, you can create a new function, which calls your original function, and passes it the parameters:

```
callback: () => drawCharts(data)
```